# Docker collabora office with nextcloud on nginx, debian stopped working

Tags: debian, nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have a Debian 9 LEMP server up and running since 2 years.
Nextcloud, Collabora Office in docker, with Letsencrypt certificates.
Everything runs smooth. I always did my updates to the latest versions.

Since I don't use web office to often, I found out today that the collabora office stopped working a time ago.

So I stopped and rm'ed the docker image. Pulled a newer version.
Still not working.

So I : `nc -z -v -w5 localhost 9980`

```
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9980 (?) open
```

And: `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:9980 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
```

My setup is like here:
https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/nginx-reverse-proxy/

and here:
https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it. In my nginx reverse proxy configuration there was a entry missing:

```
# Capabilities
location ^~ /hosting/capabilities {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9980;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

I found it by checking the error.log of nginx.

[error] 1205#1205: *5856 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/hosting/capabilities" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /hosting/capabilities HTTP/1.1", host: ""

Odd.